# pdfbox external signing. After signing document, open it in adobe reader it says invalid signature as document has been altered

Tags: java, pdfbox, signature

We are using pdfbox library to sign a document and also integrated HSM service to sign document hash and get signed hash. But the problem is that we are getting an error in Adobe Reader saying "invalid signature as document has been altered since signature was applied."

Here is the code snippet for the signature:

```java
public void signPdfExternally() throws Exception {
    PDDocument document;
    File pdfToBeSigned;
    File signedPdfFile;
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    byte[] cmsSignature;
    ExternalSigningSupport externalSigningSupport;
    try {
        pdfToBeSigned = new File("testPdf.pdf");
        signedPdfFile = new File(pdfToBeSigned.getParent(), pdfToBeSigned.getName().substring(0, pdfToBeSigned.getName().lastIndexOf('.')) + "_signed.pdf");
        document = Loader.loadPDF(pdfToBeSigned);
        output = new FileOutputStream(signedPdfFile);
        loadExternalCert(eSignCertProvider.getCertificateChain());
        extractPrivateKey();
        document.addSignature(signature());
        externalSigningSupport = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
        cmsSignature = sign(externalSigningSupport.getContent());
        externalSigningSupport.setSignature(cmsSignature);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private PDSignature signature() {
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    signature.setName("Test User");
    signature.setLocation("Some location");
    signature.setReason("Testing");
    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    return signature;
}

// Signing document and attaching certificate to the pdf
public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException {
    try {
        loadExternalCert(eSignCertProvider.getCertificateChain());
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // External service that signs document hash and gives back signed hash as a signature
        byte[] signature = HsmServiceProvider.signContent(content.readAllBytes(), "Testing1234");
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

        List<Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(externalCertificateChain);
        JcaCertStore certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        Attribute attr = new Attribute(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(content.readAllBytes())));
        ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        v.add(attr);
        SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new BcDigestCalculatorProvider()).setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(new AttributeTable(v)));
        AlgorithmIdentifier sha256withRSA = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA256withRSA");
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(externalCertificateChain[0].getEncoded());
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(builder.build(new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sha256withRSA, new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sha256withRSA)).build(PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(this.privateKey.getEncoded())), new JcaX509CertificateHolder(cert)));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData s = gen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature), false);
        return s.getEncoded();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}

how to solve document has been altered error
```

Comment: Hhmmm, your code is weird, it looks like plugged together only based on matching types, not on semantics... you may want to look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76969040/1729265) and other answers referenced from there.

Comment: Thank you so much mkl. I looked at the answers referenced by you. Now I am able to fix the error "Signature is invalid". Again thanks for your help 

Comment: Great that that helped. Is it ok to mark your question as duplicate of that other question then?

Comment: Sure sir, you can mark my question  as a duplicate